# HTML File doesnt update with PHP and JQuery .load()

Tags: javascript, php, html

Please help, this really made me stuck. I have HTML file "newsfeed.html" that loads onto another page using JQuery `.load()` and I have PHP file "ajax_fetch_posts.php". My HTML file uses XMLHTTPREQUEST Object to fetch data from my PHP file, my problem begun when I noticed that everytime I update my HTML file code and HIT refresh on my browsers reload, that page doesn't change at all, whatever I do it keeps on displaying the same all over and over again. I also tried to clear my browser cache or cookies but it's useless. Is this some sort of `<meta>` tag? or `header()` in php? It seemed my page being kept as cached copy or is this some sort of virus?

Here is my html code so far:

```
 <div id="newsfeed_container" class="newsfeed-container">
    <div id="post">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <table border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <tr><!-- RESERVED! --></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font: 11px 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;width:360px;">
                                <div style='width:207px;word-wrap: break-word;white-space: pre-wrap;border:0px solid; font-size: 11px;position:relative;z-index:10;margin:4px 0px 0px 7px;width:280px;display:inline-block;width:300px;background-color:#f7f2f1;box-shadow:-1px 1px 0px #eec7c7;-moz-box-shadow:-1px 1px 0px #eec7c7;-webkit-box-shadow:-1px 1px 0px #eec7c7;padding: 3px;left:50px;' id='div_shout_handle'>this is an example</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img src='images/default.jpg' height='50' style='border:1px solid #CDB3AB'/>
                                <img src="images/asset/shout-body-tail.png" style="position:relative;top:-20px;"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr><!-- RESERVED! --></tr>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Here's JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var form = new FormData();

        form.append('EmailAd', EmailAd);
        form.append('UserID', UserID);
        form.append('Studentnumber', Studentnumber);

        xhr.open('POST', 'ajax/ajax_fetch_post.php', true);

        xhr.onload = function() {
            var div_shout_handle = document.getElementById('div_shout_handle');
                div_shout_handle.innerHTML = this.response;     
        }

        xhr.send(form);
});
```

PHP File:

```
<?php

   include '../include/class.inc.php';
   $array_post = array();

   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
       $pdo = new dbConnection;
       $pdo->dbInstance($db);
       $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts");
       $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       $stmt->execute();

     while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
          array_push($array_post,   $row['Content']);                               
     }  

      echo json_encode(array('Posts' => $array_post));
  }


?>
```

Please help, this probably sound so easy.

Comment: So hang on, is the PHP returning `json` and you want to loop through this json?

Comment: I'm also trying to figure out what OP's expected result is. Can you please adjust your question to include your *expected result*.

Comment: @JamieHutber yes it is

Comment: @snh its just like dont want something with your HTML file and modify the code, FILE>SAVE and hit F5 on keyboard and boom! congratulation nothing changed